# Space as a leader in emacs with evil

Tags: emacs, key-binding

I am trying to define `Space` as a `<leader>` in Emacs using `evil-leader`.
If I set `,` or `\`, then it works. but it does not work with `Space` for some reason. There are no errors. Mb something redefines it, but how I can discover where is a problem?

I use the following line in my `.emacs`

```
(evil-leader/set-leader "<Space>")
```

Comment: Try the Evil list if you don't get an answer here: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.vim-emulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `(evil-leader/set-leader "<SPC>")` is the right way.

I've create a pull request for it, see https://github.com/cofi/evil-leader/pull/17